# Not able to create metro style Message Box in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, caliburn.micro, mahapps.metro

i have tried to create message box using this article, but cant compile it wihout errors.
The article is here: http://www.sjurvarhaug.com/metro-style-messagebox-in-wpf

It is giving many errors like, "such type not found" and etc...
I have uploaded project to skydrive. You can download and test ti.
https://skydrive.live.com/redir?resid=89FD450CC0CC74DA!181

Thanks.

Comment: y not put a comment there and ask the author regarding these errors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add

```
   <BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="bool2vis" />
```

in the resources section then update your bindings to

```
Converter={StaticResource bool2vis}
```

that should sort it out :)

shame the tutorial misses that though..

cheers.
ste.

Comment: Yes the first error is solves. But next is: The name 'NotifyOfPropertyChange' does not exist in the current context

Comment: Where does that happen? can you upload another sample with what you have so far and can you also include any required DLL's